# UWP app dont send request when use app package but in local machine work

Tags: c++, uwp, request

I create a uwp that do a post request to my api, when i run in local machine works but when i create a app package and install and i send the request, nothing happens, anyone know why this happen or what i can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

To make a request to an API, you have to declare that capability in the manifest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

In your case, it would be the "internetClient" capability, declared in the manifest this way:

```
<Package>
  <!-- ... -->
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
  <!-- ... -->
</Package>
```

For other permissions, like access to files, calls (In Windows Phone), etc, it's the same

Comment: my package manager have this capabilitie, i really dont understand why, when i run in local machine works, but when i create a package dont send...

Comment: Does it throw some kind of exception, return an answer, or something like that? Can you add your request code?

Comment: The request happen in a background task that activate when receive a notification, i dont knowif it's because I'm sending the request to localhost, then the package doesn't send to localhost, only the local machine, do you think that could be it?

Comment: Packaged or not, localhost should resolve the same way I think. I'd suggest you to log in some way (to a file, for example) the requests that it's sending and it's responses/errors/exceptions Anything you could log should be useful. It's really strange that nothing happens, there shoudl be probably something there

Comment: Okay Iván, i will log, thanks so much, I tell you what happened

Comment: For access local network, you need also enable [private networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/networking-basics#capabilities) capability and app network [loopback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback).

Comment: i already put the private networks capability and dont work, i dont understand, when i print the response, the print doesn't work

Comment: `the print doesn't work`

It's strange, is the program reaching that line? Another print there works?

What are you printing? Can you print the HTTP status code? Maybe show us the request and log code to check if there's something strange there

Comment: Here is my code: 
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:3001/...", body);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Debug.WriteLine(responseString); 
The print dont happen, i tested a lot of solutions and dont work, i deployed my api, but it didn't work either. I don't understand why request doesn't work when I create a package, but locally it works

Comment: First, I would add some message to the WriteLine, to avoid printing "nothing" if the content is empty. Like $"Response {responseString}".

Also, I'd add another WriteLine before the PostAsync, to ensure that the logs can be seen, that the code reaches that point, and if the PostAsync is throwing an exception, as if an exception is thrown, the actual WriteLine won't execute.

Comment: i already added a log on top the responseString log, all the things that is below the postAsync, dont work. I see something strange, i have another request in app.cs, this request work, but the request in my background task dont work, i need to do something to do a request in background task?

Comment: I use breakpoints and the app stop in this row 
var response = await client.PostAsync("localhost:3001...", body);
Dont have any exception, its because is in a background task? Is the same of my another post that's working

Comment: While using a breakpoint, what's the value of "response"? You're debugging the installed package, right?

Comment: i debbug in local machine, when the post request happens, the program close but post works, the program just close

Comment: Have you debug the code in the debug model?

Comment: yes, i debug in debug model, but when request in background task run, the program just close and the request work (in local machine), but when i create a app and do the request, the resquest dont happen

Comment: I'm testing yet and i dont know what  is happening with my app, the app close when arrive in breakpoint in background task, i have another request out of background task, in main app, this request works, but the request in background task dont work, i really dont know why